# Convert .CSV file into XML file then send to Web Service

Tags: xml, visual-studio, web-services, csv

I have a .CSV file and was wondering if there is any process on visual studio or visual web developer to convert it into an XML file and then send it to a Web Service? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't anything like this. CSV is simply comma separated and contains only values. Also it is not hierarchical like XML.

Answer (score 0):

No, because there is no way for Visual Studio to know what format you want the XML to be in.  You can, however, easily parse a CSV file and use the .NET XML libraries to do the conversion yourself.  Finally, you can use the web services libraries to consume a web service and send the xml to it.